# Printing color to the python command line

Tags: python, printing, colors, command-line-interface

I was working away on a project in python, and I was wondering how to pront with color. I know of colorama, and termcolor, but they are not working.
When I run this code in my python interpreter (PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) the colors work fine, but in the command line, the following:

```
import colorama
print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'Green text')
```

Outputs as:

```
[32mGreenText
```

Between the '[', and the begining of the line, their is a strange character. I know it is not ASCII, and probabaly not Unicode, so I took a screenshot of it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7cIc.png)
-I do not know if that worked, this is my first post-

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python

Comment: Just for future reference; phrases such as ' _HELP ME!!!!!!!!_ ', do not help you get better answers and frankly just look bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `colorama.init()` before `print()`:

```
import colorama
colorama.init(autoreset=True)
print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'Green text')
```